# Why my integers array is 8 bit size even if it's storing 3 integers?

Tags: c++

I created the sortArray function that should sort my integers array. Inside this function I'm creating arrSize variable dividing the size of whole array by one of the array items. I'm using this function to sort array containing 3 elements and the arrSize variable is returning 2. Why is that happening? Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void sortArray(int *array);

int main() {
    int numbers[3] = {0, 0, 0};

    cout << "Enter three integers: ";
    if (cin >> numbers[0] >> numbers[1] >> numbers[2])
    {
        sortArray(numbers);
        cout << "Entered numbers: " << numbers[0] << numbers[1] << numbers[2];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You entered wrong data";
    }

    return 0; }

void sortArray(int *array) {
    int arrSize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    cout << sizeof(array) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(array[0]) << endl;
    bool changed = true;
    while (changed)
    {
        changed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize - 1; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = i;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: `int *array` This is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: A pointer is not an array.  Within the function `sortArray()` the calculation `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` does not give the size of the array `numbers` that was passed by `main()`.   Instead, `sizeof(array)` is equal to `sizeof(int *)`, and `sizeof(array[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`.     Both of those sizes are implementation defined (so vary between compilers) but on a 64-bit system it is common for `sizeof(int *)` to be `8` and `sizeof(int)` to be `4`.    The solution - you need to pass the length of the array by another means to the function (e.g. as an additional argument).